# How to apply aggregations on grouped fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, search-engine

On my eCommerce store I want to only include the first item in each group (grouped by item_id) in the final results. At the same time I don't want to lose my aggregations (little numbers next to attributes that indicate how many items with that attribute are found).

Here is a little example:

Suppose I make a search for items and only 25 show up. This is the result for the color aggregation that I currently get:

---

- black (65)
- green (32)
- white (13)

And I want it to be:

---

- black (14)
- green (6)
- white (5)

The numbers should amount to the total number the user actually sees on the page.

How could I achieve that with Elasticsearch? I have tried both Grouping (Top Hits) and Field Collapsing and both don't seem to fit my use case. Solr does it almost by default with its Grouping functionality.

Comment: I think you are looking for faceting. you need to check id elastic search has the faceting feature...https://madewithlove.be/faceted-search-using-elasticsearch/

Comment: Yes, because this is what I'm currently using in Solr, but unfortunately in Elasticsearch facets have been replaced with aggregations.

Comment: ok. I did not knew this...

Answer (score -1):

It should be rather easy. When you are asking for aggregation you are simple sending request to the `_search` endpoint. Example:

```
POST /exams/_search
{
  "aggs" : {
    "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "grade" } }
  }
}
```

and in above example you will get aggregation for all the documents.

If you want to get aggregation for specific documents you just need to add specific `query` to the request body, like:

```
POST /exams/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "some query string here"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "grade" } }
  }
}
```

and you can send `size` and `from` parameters as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to apply my aggregations like color, size, price to the already collapsed results. I don't see in your query, where the results are grouped/collapsed. Because if I collapse the results on the field, Elasticsearch ignores those when it calculates aggregations.

Comment: Maybe the only way to group the results is by grouping them using SQL before indexing, but that seems cumbersome and kind of misses the point. But if that's what I have to do I'll do it.